# Definition and Usage of Divot

Tags: etymology, word-usage

Definition of Divot:

(1) a piece of turf cut out of the ground by a golf club in making a stroke.

(2) a small hole left by something.

(sample usage): "After getting my wisdom teeth extracted, they left a small divot in my gums to heal."

As a native English speaker, I would commonly use the word "divot" to explain a small hole left by something. Evidently, this is not a common definition of the word.

What can explain this usage I hear so often?

Comment: Can you help us understand what needs to be explained exactly. For one thing, are you saying "divot" is not common -- or is common (you hear so often)?

Comment: Your question requires refining.What are you asking? If it is origin of the word "divot", you should plainly ask for that. Thanks

Comment: And please provide a cite for those definitions you quoted.

Comment: Just in case anyone is totally confused by this question, [This](https://www.bonappetit.com/recipe/sesame-balls-jian-dui) is the sort of thing the OP is referring to. *Shape dough into balls that are about 1½" in diameter (you should have 10). Working one at a time, flatten into a pancake and make a **divot** in the center. Place ½ tsp. prune filling in **divot** and wrap dough over. Roll into a smooth ball, pinching together any holes.*

Comment: Golf clubs request golfers to 'replace all divots'. They are asking people to fill the hole in with the clods of turf.

Comment: Oxford Dictionaries Online attests also: "divot - A small hole made by the removal of a divot." The use of it to describe a small hole made by the removal of something else would be figurative.

Comment: So it's "a divot made by the removal of a divot"? Gotta love English speakers @MetaEd  it reminds me of  "sanction"  or "bone/debone"

Comment: @PhilSweet is correct in the usage I thought the word afforded.

Comment: @Clare Yep, but most of us are pretty conditioned to accept that by now. It's the making of a divot with out removing anything that tends to grate.

Comment: Interestingly, [MW Online](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/divot) cites _Bon Appetit_ for "Working one at a time, flatten into a pancake and make a _divot_ in the center" as a "recent example of DIVOT from the Web," and yet does not budge on its definitions of _divot_. Both U.S. dictionaries seem to be fighting current real-world usage on this point, although the extent of that usage remains unclear.

Comment: Hello, Amacelia. ELU requires that reasonable research from respected authorities be given alongside questions, together with links where possible, and copyright laws require that correct attributions be given.

Answer (score 2):

In its entry for *divot*, *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2013) does not include any meaning that is at all similar to "a small hole left by something." The MW definitions focus on the material removed, rather than on the resulting void:

> **divot** *n.* {alter. of earlier Sc *devat*, fr. ME (Sc) *duvat*} (1586) **1** *Scot* **:** a square of turf or sod **2 :** a loose piece of turf (as one dug from a golf fairway in making a shot)

*The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language*, fifth edition (2010) shares the *Eleventh Collegiate*'s understanding of the term:

> **divot** *n.* **1.** A piece of turf torn up by a golf club in striking a ball, or by a horse's hoof. **2.** *Scots* A thin square of turf or sod used for roofing. {Scots, a turf.}

It is not at all surprising that a person hearing the statement "Your last golf stroke left a divot" might suppose that the divot was the gash in the earth and not the clump of turf torn out of it. Nevertheless, the two dictionaries I consulted have not yet conceded that "small hole" is a correct application or interpretation of the word.

Comment: But the phrase "replace your divot" probably ought to clue them in.

Comment: WordNet 3.0 is one source that has the definition "(golf) the cavity left when a piece of turf is cut from the ground by the club head in making a stroke; "it was a good drive but the ball ended up in a divot", and this appears on the [results page at Onelook](https://www.onelook.com/?w=Divot&ls=a) and in the thesaurus portion of [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/divot). Not that I'm persuaded.

Comment: And as MetaEd found at what is usually my first stop, ODO.... "1.1 A small hole made by the removal of a divot.
‘if your ball finds a divot to rest in’" with sample uses. So, you know, language is always a-changing.

Comment: [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/divot?q=Divot): "a small hole in an area of grass, especially one made by a golf club (= stick for hitting) or ball; a piece of grass that has been cut out, leaving such a hole"

Comment: Also see this: http://www.golfchannel.com/news/golf-central-blog/no-plan-change-rule-ball-fairway-divot/  With a photo of a ball in a "fairway divot."  So it seems that in use are divot as the chunk taken out of the ground; divot  as the hole left, and also "divot hole."  As @Clare said, always a-changing.